# Error with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I am new to AngularJS and here I am facing an issue. I have a page with submit button, when i click on submit modal has to open and the data from URL has to be present inside modal. Right now, modal opens but that is empty and not fetching data from URL.Below is the code I have:

Index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="plunker">
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.js"></script>
<script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.6.0.js"></script>
<script src="example.js"></script>
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div ng-controller="ModalDemoCtrl">
<script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
<div class="modal-header">
<h3>Modal</h3>
</div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            {{items}}
        </div>
<div class="modal-footer">
  <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="cancel()">Close</button>
 </div>
 </script>
    <button class="btn" ng-click="open()">Submit</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

example.js:

```
angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);
var ModalDemoCtrl = function ($scope, $modal, $log, $http) {


 //$scope.items = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'];

$scope.open = function () {
    debugger
    $http.get("URL")
      .success(function (response) {
          debugger
          $scope.items = response.data.Table;
          console.log(response.Table);
      });
          var modalInstance = $modal.open({
              templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
              controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
              resolve: {
                  items: function () {
                      return $scope.items;
                  }
              }
          });        
};
};
var ModalInstanceCtrl = function ($scope, $modalInstance, items) {
$scope.items = items;

$scope.cancel = function () {
    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
};
};
```

Errors Iam getting after clicking on submit is:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
> (Not Found)
>
> Failed to load resource: the server responded (url I am using for  local host) with a status of 405 (Method Not Allowed)

[Here is a demo plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/tH97V6m54P7TFZzcS8CA?p=preview)

Where is this going wrong? Hope anyone can help. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You could see what the URL is returning from the rest client on chrome or Postman. Modal seems to be working fine.

Comment: @Dev-One: yup URL is working fine in browser. But the data is not fetched inside the modal and even with `console.log()`, i couldn't see any object on console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated your code little bit...
Now its working fine

```
angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);
var ModalDemoCtrl = function ($scope, $modal, $log, $http) {

    $scope.open = function () {
        $http.get("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
          .success(function (response) {
              var modalInstance = $modal.open({
                  templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
                  controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
                  resolve: {
                      items: function () {
                          return response;
                      }
                  }

              });
          });


    };
};

var ModalInstanceCtrl = function ($scope, $modalInstance, items) {
    $scope.items = items;

    $scope.cancel = function () {
        $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };
};
```

Issue was the return in the resolve function.now its fine.
Another thing, your results are set of data in an array. so you have to loop it.

Comment: This is fine with the sample url, but in the original url i have JSON data as:{"Table":[{"......"}]}. So i have update code in resolve as  resolve: {                      items: function () { $scope.items = response.data.Table;return $scope.items;   } . Is this correct?

Comment: No need to assign 
"$scope.items = response.data.Table;"

just return "response.data.Table;"

Comment: can you get me the plunker

Comment: try something like this "return response.Table"

Comment: {"Table":[{"ID":"01","Name":"John"},{"ID":"02","Name":"Jerry"}}]}

Comment: Done the same.. bt getting XMLHttpRequest cannot load Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 405 error. Should this be set on server side??

Comment: can you get me the plunker

Comment: if you just return response whats happening ?
like  
"return response"

Comment: I think its something to do with the server. try get the original url and check in the browser for result.

Comment: I could get result from url in browser, bt not from code.. I'll check it on server side.. Thanks a lot Nifal Nizar for ur time and i have already accepted your answer and voted+1, but its not reflecting as my rep is below 15..thanx a lot

Answer (score 0):

As it is ajax call and modalInstance open method is outside of ajax call success method, it may or may not return data.

modalInstance logic seems to be working fine. As Dev-One suggested check you rest service, if it is returning data or not.

Please refer to this working plunkr with some sample data

http://plnkr.co/edit/tH97V6m54P7TFZzcS8CA

```
$http.get("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts").success(function (response) {
              debugger
              $scope.items = response;
              console.log(response);
               var modalInstance = $modal.open({
                  templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
                  controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
                  resolve: {
                      items: function () {
                          return $scope.items;
                      }
                  }

              });
          });
```

Comment: Tried with $http.get("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts").success(function (response) {,  now the error on console is:` Cannot read property 'Table' of undefined`

Answer (score 0):

In the call method
$http.get("URL")
I don't see a correct url. because you have specified the url as "url". it should be something like "localhost:8000/GetItems"

And make sure you open the model in the success method.
Otherwise you model won't get the data.

Comment: I have mentioned it here as "URL", but have tried with the original one.

Comment: are you getting anything inside the success method?

Comment: No couldn't find anything in success.  Please check the plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/tH97V6m54P7TFZzcS8CA?p=preview with url updated in httpget()

Comment: I tried your get a method with below codes and im getting the results.

Comment: <html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  
 <button class="btn" ng-click="open()">Submit</button>
  
</body>
<script>
 var angular = angular.module('myApp', []);
 
 angular.controller('myCtrl', function($scope,$http) {
  $scope.open = function () {
   $http.get("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
   .success(function (response) {
    $scope.items = response.data.Table;;
   });
  };
 });
</script>
</html>

Comment: but I dont see "$scope.items = response.data.Table;" as valid. because your response is an array

Comment: I have updated thye code as ` $scope.items = response;`could you please check this http://plnkr.co/edit/tH97V6m54P7TFZzcS8CA?p=preview

Comment: check the next answer which I post.